# How to load data into a CanvasJS graph

Tags: javascript, json, graph, canvasjs

I am learning how to get the data from a JSON file to be displayed on a graph in CanvasJS. I only need the integer values from this JSON file as the Y axis values. the X axis values at the moment can be hardcoded or anything. eventually they will have to be a timestamp. I currently am struggling with thinking of how to get the data i need from this file to a variable and then access the correct piece of data in order to load it into the graph. Thank you!
this is the JSON files contents:

```
  "tables": [
    {
      "tableName": "RSRP",
      "series": [
        {
          "index": "",
          "column": "Time",
          "size": 31
        },
        {
          "index": "",
          "column": "RSRP",
          "size": 31
        },
        {
          "index": "",
          "column": "RSRQ",
          "size": 31
        },
        {
          "index": "",
          "column": "SNR",
          "size": 31
        }
      ],
      "internalChange": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your JSON data and parse it to the dataPoints [format accepted by CanvasJS](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/working-with-data/). After parsing the data, you can pass that dataPoints to chart options to render the chart as per your requirement. Take a look at the code snippet below.

```js
var jsonData = {
  "tables": [
    {
      "tableName": "RSRP",
      "series": [
        {
          "index": "",
          "column": "Time",
          "size": 31
        },
        {
          "index": "",
          "column": "RSRP",
          "size": 31
        },
        {
          "index": "",
          "column": "RSRQ",
          "size": 31
        },
        {
          "index": "",
          "column": "SNR",
          "size": 31
        }
      ],
      "internalChange": true
    }
  ]
}

var dps = [];

jsonData.tables[0].series.forEach(function(data) {
  dps.push({label: data.column, y: data.size})
})

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  theme: "light2", 
  title:{
    text: "Data from JSON"
  },
  data: [
    {
      type: "column",
      dataPoints: dps
    }
  ]
});
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
```